# Salesforce Knowledge - Javascript Injection to display alert message.

Tags: javascript, knowledge, standard-objects, customization, richtextarea

In Standard Knowledge Page, I want to display an alert box based on some content within Rich Text box.

Can we do JavaScript Injection in any standard page in Salesforce?

Please suggest!

Comment: No you cannot..

Comment: @Eric any other workaround that you can suggest ?